# how to increase real time factor while doing simulation

Tags: ros-melodic, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I load an empty world in gazebo,the real time factor is close to 1,but if I load a pr2 model in the gazebo environment,the value of it decrease to 0.2.How to increase the value of real time factor when doing simulation with pr2?
I tried modifying the physics link in the wrold file,but it didn't help...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25190/how-to-increase-real-time-factor-while-doing-simulation/) by [Carrot12138](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/27325/carrot12138/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-05-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

On the left panel, go to the World Tab and click on Physics. Then change the real time update rate to 0. This will make gazebo run as fast as possible.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Carrot12138](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/27325/carrot12138/) on 2020-06-07**:
Thank you for your answer，this solution works well in some situation.My problem seems to be related to the hardware configuration of my computer,so that after I modified the physics tag,the robot still move slow in the gazebo.

**Comment by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) on 2020-06-08**:
FYI as fast as possible does not mean faster than real time. If your model is too complicated, or your computer doesn't have enough resources, gazebo might still run slower than real time.